# Getting mouse click location of a label in qt

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, location, mouseevent

I googled around and found [this forum thread](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/qt-widget-suitable-for-displaying-an-image-and-getting-mouse-click-position-673808/) in which the OP seems to have had the exact problem I am having. The question is, how would I inherit from `QLabel` and reimplement the mousepressed event? I'm guessing it would be something like this:

```
class CustomLabel : public QLabel
{
public:
    //what about the constructors?
    void mousePressEvent ( QMouseEvent * ev );
}

void CustomLabel::mousePressEvent ( QMouseEvent * ev )
{
    QPoint = ev->pos();
    //I want to have another function get the event position.
    //How would I achieve this? It's void!
    //Is there perhaps some way to set up a signal and slot with the position?
}
```

And after I have successfully created a `CustomLabel` class, how would I be able to put it in design view?

Comment: Did you find the second solution of putting the label back to the main window?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can set up a signal on your `CustomLabel` class and have your overridden version of `mousePressEvent` emit it. i.e.

```
class CustomLabel : public QLabel
{
Q_OBJECT
signals:
    void mousePressed( const QPoint& );

public:
    CustomLabel( QWidget* parent = 0, Qt::WindowFlags f = 0 );
    CustomLabel( const QString& text, QWidget* parent = 0, Qt::WindowFlags f = 0 );

    void mousePressEvent( QMouseEvent* ev );
};

void CustomLabel::mousePressEvent( QMouseEvent* ev )
{
    const QPoint p = ev->pos();
    emit mousePressed( p );
}

CustomLabel::CustomLabel( QWidget * parent, Qt::WindowFlags f )
    : QLabel( parent, f ) {}

CustomLabel::CustomLabel( const QString& text, QWidget* parent, Qt::WindowFlags f )
    : QLabel( text, parent, f ) {}
```

The constructors just mimic those of the base `QLabel` and therefore simply pass their arguments straight on to the corresponding base constructors.

Comment: How would I add such a custom label to design view?

Comment: @wrongusername: I'm afraid I don't know how to do that bit. Sorry.

Comment: it's okay, don't worry, I ended up using an event filter instead

Answer (score 3):

just like this :D

```
void CustomLabel::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *ev) 
{
QString x = QString::number(ev->x());
QString y = QString::number(ev->y());
qDebug() << x << "," << y;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it just me, or doesn't `QMouseEvent` already give the information you need?

> int QMouseEvent::x () const
>
> Returns the x position of the mouse cursor, relative to the widget that received the event.
>
> See also y() and pos().
>
> int QMouseEvent::y () const
>
> Returns the y position of the mouse cursor, relative to the widget that received the event.
>
> See also x() and pos().

Ref: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7.old/qmouseevent.html#x

Comment: Oh okay, sorry! How would I know if there's a mouseclick and then get the position?