# How to get mouse input and keyboard input into a C++ application in ubuntu environment?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, mouseevent

```
class MouseEventHandler {
   void leftClick() {
     cout << "leftClickDetected" <<endl;
   }  
   
   void rightClick() {
     cout << "rightClickDetected" <<endl;
   }

   pair<int, int> getCursorPosition() {
   }
};
```

Hi all,
I am trying to write a mouse event handler library that would respond to leftclicks and rightclicks, get current curson positions etc, when the the application is launched. I am not sure how to write the callee for the event handler class. What C API can I use to get my functions in the EventHandler class called in response to mouse events? Please advise on how to go about this.

Thanks

Comment: Many ways to do it, e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519759/how-to-read-low-level-mouse-click-position-in-linux, or with QT https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349769/getting-mouse-click-location-of-a-label-in-qt

Comment: Are you trying to intercept mouse events globally or the clicks on the window of your application?

Comment: @AlanBirtles What would be the solution for either case?

Comment: You should follow the links above